# Open app automatically at system startup in dock

Tags: macos, cocoa, startup, boot

I have a MAC OS X application and I want to launch my app automatically in the dock when user opens his PC. I know a user can explicitly select an app to "alway open on startup" but what if user dont select that option. Thats why I want to do it automatically (myself) once he/she install my app. Later he can remove my app from launching at the startup though. Kindly suggest me some solution or guide me to the right path. Not very familiar with Mac development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html). What you are looking for is an agent.

Comment: I'd say this can't be done without plist :) Just read about agents in that doc